# Getting data from standalone into existing replica set without downtime

Tags: mongodb

I have a standlone mongo instance running on AWS and now I created managed replica set using the mongo cloud manager (hosted on AWS as well). No I would like to get my data over from the standalone instance into the replica set if possible without downtime.

Shutting down all services generating a backup of the standalone instance and importing this into the replica set might be the possibility with a downtime.

If I add the standalone node as another replica set member to the new replica set what will happen then? will my standalone instance content be deleted? Or will this be synced to all other replica set hosts as well?

Answer (score 0):

To increase security you need to have 3 systems in replica set (primary, secondary and secondary OR arbiter), having only pri/sec would cause more issues than expected.

**if you server (primary) is not started with replica set parameter activated**

> mongod --replSet "rs0"

then, you need to add entry in config file or add startup parameter `--replSet "myReplSet"` - and this will cause a breakdown in your service.

then using manual from [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#initiate-the-replica-set) you can go via steps and initiate single server replica set, then add secondary system.